# How to remove default index action on controller from laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, methods, routes, controllers

I am using Laravel 5.5 version. I defined my routes in the `routes.php` file. like this:-

```
$router->group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function($router) {
    $router->resource('/route-name', 'myController@myMethodName'); 
});
```

But when I run my application laravel gives error:-

Method `[myMethodName@index]` does not exist on `[App\Http\Controllers\myController]`.

It is by default put index action after my defined action in the routes.
It is working fine in the laravel 5.3 version. Please solve my problem..

Comment: `$router->resource()` expects only controller name as the 2nd argument. You added method name as well. You probably want to use `$router->get(path, controller@method)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try this as @devk told in comment:

```
$router->get('/route-name', 'myController@myMethodName');
```

Answer (score 0):

By Default **`resource`** Request create `CRUD` requests in routes. For the following methods in `Controller`.

- Index(GET)
- Create(GET)
- Store(POST)
- Show(GET)
- edit(GET)
- Update(PUT/PATCH)
- Delete(DELETE)

You can't pass method name in `resource` route.

> If you want to override any of them. you have to write new one `route` below the `resource` *Route*. Like

```
Route::get('url','Controller@newMethod');
```

And Change the method name in Controller with *`newMethod`*
For more detail check [laravel documents](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/controllers#resource-controllers)